# Text characters not being displayed correctly from SQL > Pandas > CSV file

Tags: python, sql, pandas, utf-8

I have an application that saves tweets from Twitter.  However when I download them and save the data as a CSV it changes a lot of the characters.  I can understand if there were emojis however character such an apostrophe gets converted to **â€™** which is confusing.

**I though it was the encoding setting, so I set that to 'utf-8', with no success.**

The data is requested from my postgres server using psycopg2 using the following code, which converts the results to a pandas dataframe:

```
        # Try statement to catch SQL errors
        try:
            with connect (
                database = 'postgres',
                user = security['DB_USER'],
                password = security['DB_PASS'],
                host = security['DB_HOST'],
                port = security['DB_PORT']
            ) as conn:
                with conn.cursor(name='cache_builder') as cursor:
                    sql_object = sql.SQL(query).format(sql.Identifier('tweets'))
                    cursor.itersize = 100000
                    cursor.execute(sql_object)
                    df_results = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
        
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'\n>>> SQL ERROR - {err}')
```

And then I save the data as a CSV file using this line:

```
df_results.to_csv(open(save_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8'), sep=',')
```

[image: Image: How it is displayed in my postgres SQL server.]

[image: Image how it appears on a CSV once saved]

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `" we’re ".encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `' weâ€™re '`…

Comment: Any idea how I can prevent it?